# Cantor set question

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that for any $x, 0<x<1$ there are two points $a,b$ inside the Cantor set such that $a-b=x$?
I suppose that I should use ternary representation, but I can't find a way to do a proper proof.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: See [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/cantor3.shtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an intersection of closed sets $\bigcap_i C_i$ (with $C_0 = [0,1]$, $C_1 = [0,1] \setminus (1/3,2/3)$, etc), the Cantor set $C$ is closed.

Hence if a sequence $(u_n)$ satisfying $u_n \in C_n$ for all $n$ converges, its limit $u$ lies in $C$.

Indeed, the sequence of sets $(C_n)$ is decreasing for the inclusion, so if $u \not\in C$ there would exist a $N$ such that $u \notin C_N$. So there would be an open neighborhood $U$ of $u$ such that $U \cap C_N = \emptyset$, thus $U \cap C_M = \emptyset$ so $u_M \not\in U$ for all $M\geq N$ which contradicts $u_n \rightarrow u$.

So you just have to show by induction that given $x \in [0,1]$, there exists for all $n$ a pair of elements $a_n, b_n \in C_n$ verifying $a_n - b_n = x$.

Indeed, then you can just use compactness to extract two converging sequences $(a'_n)$ and $(b'_n)$ from $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ respectively. You would then have :

- $\forall n, \quad a'_n - b'_n = x$
- $\forall n, \quad a'_n, b'_n \in C_n$
- $a'_n \rightarrow a, \quad b'_n \rightarrow b$

Thus, $a-b=x$, and by the argument above you have $a,b\in C$.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer ! +1 . Could you elaborate a bit more on the proof? I just started studying the Cantor set and I must admit it's all pretty ambiguous to me at the moment.

Comment: Sure, I will edit. But do you mean, elaborate on the topology argument - stating that if a sequence satisfying $u_n \in C_n$ for all $n$ converges then it converges in $C$ - or on the induction argument ? I didn't write the full induction on purpose because I think it is a rather elementary and pleasant exercice to solve and it shouldn't take too much effort, but I can put it down if you prefer.

Comment: @Victor Drawing a picture may help. For small values of $n$, draw the Cartesian product $C_n\times C_n$ in the $xy$-plane, and see how the mapping $(x,y)\to x-y$ projects $C_n\times C_n$ diagonally onto the interval $[-1,1]$ of the horizontal axis. (Imagine the shadow cast by $C_n\times C_n$ on the $x$-axis if a sun is shining from $r=\infty,\theta=\frac\pi4$.)